# Egit fetch from origin vs fetch from upstream

Tags: git, git-merge, egit, git-fetch

1) what is fetch from origin and fetch from upstream in EGIT?

In some workspace, I just see fetch from origin, in other workspace, I just see fetch from upstream.

[image]

[image]

2) I am working on a branch (e.g. branchA) in my local workspace, then I want to merge the change from remote master branch, what should I do?

Comment: `origin` and `upstream` are just different names for remotes

Comment: But why sometimes the menu is fetch from upstream and sometimes the menu is fetch from origin?